# I want to extract 0068Y00001Sn4P6QAJ from /lightning/r/Opportunity/0068Y00001Sn4P6QAJ/view using Regex

Tags: regex

I want to extract 0068Y00001Sn4P6QAJ from below string

/lightning/r/Opportunity/0068Y00001Sn4P6QAJ/view

0068Y00001Sn4P6QAJ expecting this from my above String expression. The 0068Y00001Sn4P6QAJ always comes in between /Opportunity and / view

Comment: Which environnement, OS, tools?

Comment: `.*/Opportunity/(.+)/view`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not Regex but its a solution:

```
path = "/lightning/r/Opportunity/0068Y00001Sn4P6QAJ/view"
 
path.split("/")[4]
```

result:

'0068Y00001Sn4P6QAJ'